# Gstreamer: extract audio from video (flv), resample rate and pipe to streaming sink - can't resample to stream

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, gstreamer, resampling, jack

I am using gstreamer to extract audio from a video and resampling the audio to a different sampling rate. My pipeline worked for file to file conversation, but I couldn't setup the streaming case properly to link it to a jack interface:

File to file (works well):

gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/data/Opinion.flv ! flvdemux ! audio/mpeg ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int, channels=1 ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=16000,depth=16 ! wavenc ! filesink location=./recordingOut2.wav

File to stream (doesn't work):

gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/data/Opinion.flv ! flvdemux ! audio/mpeg ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int, channels=1 ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=16000,depth=16 ! jackaudiosink

> > WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link audioresample0 to jackaudiosink0

The following pipeline runs, but the output has the wrong sampling rate:

gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/data/Opinion.flv ! flvdemux ! audio/mpeg ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! jackaudiosink

Anything you see that I am doing wrong?

Can one resample audio and pipe to a stream output?

I have already searched around without finding any relevant solution. Any insight/pointer from you would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jackaudiosink only accepts audio/x-raw-float. You can see this from

```
gst-inspect-0.10 jackaudiosink
```

Answer (score 0):

As ensonic suggested, try changing your pipeline to be:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/data/Opinion.flv ! flvdemux ! \
audio/mpeg ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-float, channels=1 ! \
audioresample ! audio/x-raw-float, rate=16000,depth=16 ! jackaudiosink
```

Although you probably could remove the `flvdemux ! audio/mpeg` part of it as decodebin will plug in a demuxer for you also.